# How to make a OG private?

Tags: organic-groups

I want to make an Organic group private,to be seen only from members of this group.
All the other will get an "Access denied" or something like that.
For the time being,I can see the Group but not its content.
I would also want NOT to be able to see the existance of the group,if I am not a member of it.
I am working on Drupal 7.
How to do that?
Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to enable og access control module.

see below: 
[image]

Then navigate to admin/config/group/fields, add an visibility field to your og bundle

[image]

Then edit the og bundle content type, there is a new field added to it, make your change for public or private

Comment: weirdly enough, I got the same setup and it isn't working. A user that does not belong to the group can visit it without any problem :/

Comment: nvm that. It was a conflict with the Content Access module.

Comment: @magtak, how did you solve the content access conflict?

Comment: @gilzero, thanks a lot! there is so much hidden stuff in og..

Comment: I was able to get the two access modules to play nicely by lowering the priority for the Content Access module. While editing access for a node type (`admin/structure/types/manage/TYPE/access`), there is an _Advanced_ fieldset near the bottom of the page. Inside that fieldset is the option __Give content node grants priority__. Setting that below the priority of the OG Access grants will solve the problem (setting it to -1 worked for me). The _Devel node access_ module was helpful in debugging the issue.

Comment: For Drupal 8 Og Access hasn't been ported yet. See https://github.com/Gizra/og/pull/242

Answer (score 2):

Please consider that to make a group truly "private" you have also to remove the "register" permission for non-members otherwise even if the group is "private" non-members that can guess its nid can subscribe (at http://www.example.com/group/node/[nid]/subscribe) and hence view the group's content [OG 7.x-2.2].

Answer (score 0):

This required additional steps for me. Also an unfortunately specific recipe.  Viewing `node_access` records using Devel Node Access module & block provided some pointers.

- Admin > People > Permissions
  Set Anonymous and Authenticated to can view content
- Admin > Modules
  Enable OG permissions via Organic Groups Access Control module
- Admin > Configuration > Organic Groups > OG Field Settings
  Add visibility controls (fields) to group node-types
- Configure other NAC modules, Content Access in my case, to weighted less than, before, OGAC.

Defaults are now allow viewing, unless set by the group-type node.  If you change content visibility from a group page, the subpages have to be resaved or `drush php-eval 'node_access_rebuild();'`